# if isset($_POST issue

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have one instance of where a user on my PHP site can login, and I'm trying to make a second where administrators can post announcements.

My login works beautifully, but for some reason I can't get my announcement submission to work. Despite my input fields being named appropriately, the field is being seen as "not set" when I type in a title and announcement on my form. Here is my code:

FORM:

```
        <form action="announce.php">
    <input  type="text" name="title" />
    <textarea  name="announce" cols="20" rows="2" ></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Announce" />
    </form>
```

Here is my PHP:

```
include_once 'creds.php';
$con=mysqli_connect("$db_hostname","$db_username","$db_password","$db_database");

if (isset($_POST['title']))
{
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $announce = $_POST['announce'];

$query = "INSERT INTO announcements (labname, name, author, announce)
        VALUES ($lab, $title, $username, $announce)";

$insert = mysqli_query($con, $query);

mysqli_close($con);

echo "added successfully";}
else
{
echo "something went wrong";
}
```

My other form seems to work but this one doesn't... is my syntax wrong somewhere?

Comment: `<form action="announce.php" method="post">` try this

Comment: Wow, yes, that did the trick. Thank you, I was unaware I had to include that.

Comment: Forms default to GET methods if not defined.

Comment: jerdiggity, I was getting the error "something went wrong". Once I fixed the method="post" thing, I got undefined variable errors. You fixed my problem before the parser even knew to! Thanks :)

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and have multiple SQL syntax errors. You will NEVER get anything into your database until you fix the injection problems and learn basic SQL syntax requirements for strings.

Comment: Quotes => `($lab, $title, $username, $announce)`

Answer (score 1):

Your form is submitting as a GET request, not POST.

Change this line:

```
<form action="announce.php">
```

to this:

```
<form action="announce.php" method="post">
```

---

**Edit**: I should really refresh the page before posting.  All credit to noobie-php for getting this right in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459061/if-isset-post-issue#comment37851511_24459061) 30 mins before I posted this!

Answer (score 0):

**Php :**

```
include_once 'creds.php';
$con=mysqli_connect("$db_hostname","$db_username","$db_password","$db_database");

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $announce = $_POST['announce'];

$query = "INSERT INTO announcements (labname, name, author, announce)
        VALUES ($lab, $title, $username, $announce)";

$insert = mysqli_query($con, $query);

mysqli_close($con);

echo "added successfully";}
else
{
echo "something went wrong";
}
```

i think `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` this is the problem.